# Video Watermarking

Tags: linux, software-rec, video-editing

I am looking for a solution in which I  can add watermark to the given video at given frame.

Is there any utility/tool to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

mencoder can definitely do it, although the folks I know tend to use one of the free Windows apps (so I'm guessing you could run one of them under Wine)

Also [bmovl](http://sault.org/mebox/downloads.php) should be able to do it. Check out [this thread.](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/279462-How-to-add-watermark-to-a-video-with-mencoder-or-how-to-scale-with-FFmpeg)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this programatically `mencoder` is the tool for the job. You'll need a static image (or generate one programatialy with ImageMagic, gd, etc) and some time to play with filters.